# VS2008 TFSBuild Exec command

Tags: .net, tfsbuild

I have an itemgroup set up in our VS2008 TFS TFSBuild.proj file which runs a number of test lists in sequence. In between these I need to kill the VSTestHost.exe process, because otherwise the build server eventually aborts with an out of memory exception.

The problem is I can't embed a Exec task within the item group, eg

```
<ItemGroup>
<MetaDataFile Include="$(BuildProjectFolderPath)/../../Matrix5/Matrix.vsmdi">
<TestList>Build Server</TestList>
</MetaDataFile>
<!--Kill the VSTestHost process, which may be holidng onto unreleased memory: -->
<Exec Command = "Taskkill /IM VsTestHost.exe /T /F"/>
<MetaDataFile Include="$(BuildProjectFolderPath)/../../Matrix5/Matrix.vsmdi">
<TestList>Build Server UI</TestList>
</MetaDataFile>
</ItemGroup>
```

How else can I accomplish this?

Comment: Oh no! My xml code has been trashed in this question! How do I insert xml code into a question please?

Comment: Ok, fixed the xml issue.